# Application crashes when using graphics debugger with Nsight 2.2

Tags: graphics, crash, nsight

Hi I am using **NVidia Nsight 2.2**, have a **GTS 450** card and latest drivers. Windows Vista 64 bit. When launching graphics debugger the application crashes on the very 1st drawcall. The callstack looks like this:

```
nvwgf2um.dll!5bdd7d53()     
[Frames below may be incorrect and/or missing, no symbols loaded for nvwgf2um.dll]  
nvwgf2um.dll!5be9c7f7()     
nvwgf2um.dll!5bde377e()     
nvwgf2um.dll!5bc02afb()     
nvwgf2um.dll!5bc0257b()     
nvwgf2um.dll!5bc0259e()     
nvwgf2um.dll!5bdd0612()     
nvwgf2um.dll!5bcb2292()     
nvwgf2um.dll!5bc45072()     
nvwgf2um.dll!5bcbff8c()     
D3D11SDKLayers.dll!5ea52f2f()   
Nvda.Graphics.Interception.100.dll!5dbb2853()   
Nvda.Graphics.Interception.100.dll!5dba317e()   
Nvda.Graphics.Interception.100.dll!5db99b21()   
Nvda.Graphics.Interception.100.dll!5df0150f()
```

Otherwise it runs fine by itself, only crashes if I launch through Nsight graphics debugger.
I suspect this is somehow related to me using `DX11 dynamic shader linkage`. Since my other applications that don't use dynamic linkage run fine. Anybody experienced this before, or has any info on this issue with Nsight?

Comment: Hi Rincer, any chance you can put together a repro case project?

Answer (score 0):

What driver and exact build of 2.2 are you using? (Nsight->Help->About Nsight->Build number)

Comment: Hi Sebastien, I got similar problem on GTX 670, with call stack full of "Nvda.Graphics.Interception.100.dll". Nsight build is 2.2.0.12313. NV Driver is 310.90. I could not get a simple repo since it only crashed with a complex game project, not on prototypes. The D3D debug layer did not print any error message. And the game engine worked fine until I made a capture and view that on Visual Studio. And it stucked with "retrieving texture data" shown on right panel. The crash happened 100% for me. But my teammates with similar configuration have not met the problem. Wish the information helps.

Comment: The problem might related to DX Control Panel. After changed the setting of Debug Layer from "Force On" to "Application Controlled", the crash was solved.

Answer (score 0):

The problem might be related to DX Control Panel's debug layer setting. (Please check my comments in Sebastien's answer).