# NSight crash at frame profile

Tags: opengl, visual-studio-2012, directx, framebuffer, nsight

I'm using Visual Studio 2012.
Nsight Visual Studio:

```
Version 3.2.2
Build Number: 3.2.2.13342
```

My Graphics Card Information:

```
GeForce GT 720M
Driver version: 33182
Directx 3D version: 11.1
OpenGL 4.4
```

Each time I try to pause and capture a frame, and then click in Frame Profile, my program crash. This apply for all OpenGL program in my computer. First, I though it could be due to the Operating System, so I installed the OS again, but it still crashes.
This is the stack at the time the program crashes.
[image: crash]

Before crash
[image: Before crash]
Crash
[image: crash]
I saw a crash error by NSight [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12889400/application-crashes-when-using-graphics-debugger-with-nsight-2-2), but it seems different from me.

Comment: Did you installed drivers from Nvidia or using Microsoft default driver (which only implements GL 1.1)? Quote: "Please note that this release of Nsight™ Visual Studio Edition requires NVIDIA Display Driver Release 327 or newer"

Comment: Yes, I installed the newest driver from Nvidia, and my OpenGL version is 4.4

Answer (score 1):

You're best off reporting bugs in Nsight to Nvidia. 3.2.2 is a very new version and chances are it's going to be something someone hasn't reported yet.

https://devtalk.nvidia.com/default/board/84/nsight-visual-studio-edition/

The likely culprits will be using a newer or slightly out-of-the-ordinary OpenGL extension that the tool doesn't support yet. If you want to get to the bottom of it, binary chop parts of your application out until it does capture properly and add them back in until it stops working.

Comment: it's so sad that I tried to sample a lot of OpenGL programs in my computers, and all of them are going to crash, even the simplest program such as displaying a triangle.

Comment: Your GPU is not on the supported list of GPUs by the way: https://developer.nvidia.com/nsight-visual-studio-edition-supported-gpus-full-list

Comment: I thought it applies only to GPU Debugging, and it works normally for Graphics Debugging?

Comment: So sad to hear that, there's any way to work around it? Or some other tools for debugging OpenGL 4.0?

Comment: AMD GPU PerfStudio supports debugging on all hardware (profiling is limited to AMD hardware, however you did say debugging, so this may work for you).

Comment: thanks for your advice. I will try it now. I submit my error on Nsight forum, I hope there would be some ways for solve it.